# Package "set serveroutput on" causing compilation error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using my class package template to gather two procedures into the package and after pasting and formatting everything, I came up with this error:

[image]

This is my package code. It's separated between head and body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE PAQEX AS 
PROCEDURE EX3 (P_NOMBRE IN VARCHAR2, P_LUGAR IN VARCHAR2, P_NUMERO IN NUMBER);
PROCEDURE EX2(CPN IN VARCHAR2, NUMER OUT NUMBER );

END PAQEX;

CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY PAQEX AS

  PROCEDURE EX3 (P_NOMBRE IN VARCHAR2, P_LUGAR IN VARCHAR2, P_NUMERO IN NUMBER) AS
  -- 
V_AEROPUERTO NUMBER;
V_TERMINAL NUMBER;
V_ID_AEROPUERTO AEROPUERTO.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN

-----------

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_AEROPUERTO FROM AEROPUERTO WHERE NOMBRE = P_NOMBRE AND LUGAR = P_LUGAR;

IF V_AEROPUERTO = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO AEROPUERTO (NOMBRE, LUGAR) VALUES (P_NOMBRE, P_LUGAR);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERTANDO AEROPUERTO');
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YA EXISTE EL AEROPUERTO');
END IF;

SELECT ID INTO V_ID_AEROPUERTO FROM AEROPUERTO WHERE NOMBRE = P_NOMBRE AND LUGAR = P_LUGAR;

------------

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_TERMINAL FROM TERMINAL WHERE NUMERO = P_NUMERO AND ID_AEROPUERTO = V_ID_AEROPUERTO;

IF V_TERMINAL = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO TERMINAL (NUMERO, ID_AEROPUERTO) VALUES (P_NUMERO, V_ID_AEROPUERTO);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERTANDO TERMINAL');
ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('YA EXISTE LA TERMINAL');
END IF;
  END EX3;

  PROCEDURE EX2(CPN IN VARCHAR2, NUMER OUT NUMBER ) AS
  
CURSOR CVUELO IS
SELECT CS.NOMBRE AS COMPA,MDEL.NOMBRE AS MODELL,ASA.NOMBRE AS ORIGEN,AL.NOMBRE AS DESTINO
    FROM VUELO VU
    INNER JOIN AVION AVI
    ON VU.ID_AVION = AVI.ID
    INNER JOIN COMPAÑIA CS
    ON AVI.ID_COMPAÑIA = CS.ID
    INNER JOIN MODELO MDEL
    ON AVI.ID_MODELO = MDEL.ID
    INNER JOIN PUERTA PS
    ON VU.id_puerta_salida = PS.ID
    INNER JOIN PUERTA PL
    ON VU.id_puerta_llegada = PL.ID
    INNER JOIN TERMINAL TS
    ON PS.ID_TERMINAL = TS.ID
    INNER JOIN TERMINAL TL
    ON PL.ID_TERMINAL = TL.ID
    INNER JOIN AEROPUERTO ASA
    ON TL.ID_AEROPUERTO = ASA.ID
    INNER JOIN AEROPUERTO AL
    ON TS.ID_AEROPUERTO = AL.ID
    WHERE CPN = CS.NOMBRE;
BEGIN
    NUMER:=0;
    FOR RESULTADO IN CVUELO 
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RESULTADO.COMPA || ' | ' || RESULTADO.MODELL ||' | ' ||RESULTADO.ORIGEN||' | ' ||RESULTADO.DESTINO);
    NUMER := NUMER + 1;
  END LOOP;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('La compañia ha volado '||numer||' veces');
  END EX2;
END PAQEX;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXECUTE PAQEX.EX2('AIRBUS',0);
EXECUTE PAQEX.EX3('ADOLFOS','MADRID',3);
```

I want try each procedure in the package after creating it. They work as stand-alone procedures but not in the package because of that error. Why does it not accept the `set serveroutput on` command?

Comment: If you're running all that code as one script, you're missing a `/` on a line on its own after each `END PAQEX` - for specification and body. The `SET` and `EXECUTE` are client commands, not part of the package, so run those separately from a worksheet. You appear to be using SQL Developer; not sure why you tagged with PL/SQL Developer too?)

Comment: The package is divided between body and head so i dont know if that is a single script or not

Comment: If you're now in the package body editor - not a worksheet - and clicking the compile button to get that error, then remove the SET and EXECUTE commands instead. (And don't add the slash). It's all about context...

Comment: @AlexPoole so in order to see the output of each procedure of my package, i have to remove both the execute and serveroutput? Im sorry if i sound dumb, but its a new concept explained by our teacher, and i thought, following the template was everything i had to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you could be creating this package; either from a worksheet with all of the code in one script, in which case it should look something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE PAQEX AS 
PROCEDURE EX3 (P_NOMBRE IN VARCHAR2, P_LUGAR IN VARCHAR2, P_NUMERO IN NUMBER);
PROCEDURE EX2(CPN IN VARCHAR2, NUMER OUT NUMBER );

END PAQEX;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
PACKAGE BODY PAQEX AS

...
END PAQEX;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXECUTE PAQEX.EX2('AIRBUS',0);
EXECUTE PAQEX.EX3('ADOLFOS','MADRID',3);
```

with a slash after each PL/SQL object (package specification and package body).

Or you could be creating or modifying the package from the 'New Package...' menu command, and putting the specification and body code into the relevant objects. The schema browser will show "PAQEX" under 'Packages', and if you click that you'll see a tab with the package icon and "PAQEX" containing just:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE PAQEX AS 
PROCEDURE EX3 (P_NOMBRE IN VARCHAR2, P_LUGAR IN VARCHAR2, P_NUMERO IN NUMBER);
PROCEDURE EX2(CPN IN VARCHAR2, NUMER OUT NUMBER );

END PAQEX;
```

and a "PAQEX Body" under that; and if you click that you'll see another tab with the package icon and "PAQEX Body" containing just the body code. But you seem to have included code for testing it as part of the body:

```
PACKAGE BODY PAQEX AS

...
END PAQEX;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXECUTE PAQEX.EX2('AIRBUS',0);
EXECUTE PAQEX.EX3('ADOLFOS','MADRID',3);
```

From the error image you included, you are getting the error you showed when you click the compile icon (cogs).

You need to separate out the test code from the package code. Remove the `SET` and `EXECUTE` lines from the package body tab so that just has:

```
PACKAGE BODY PAQEX AS

...
END PAQEX;
```

That should then compile, if there are no other errors.

Then to test the package, open an SQL Worksheet (right-click on the connection to see that in the contextual menu) and put in just those three statements:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXECUTE PAQEX.EX2('AIRBUS',0);
EXECUTE PAQEX.EX3('ADOLFOS','MADRID',3);
```

and click 'Run as script' or press F5. (If you click 'Run as statement' or press control-enter then it will only run the command that your cursor is currently in.)

The SQL Developer `EXECUTE` command is just a wrapper an anonymous block, so you could also combine both calls with:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
  PAQEX.EX2('AIRBUS',0);
  PAQEX.EX3('ADOLFOS','MADRID',3);
END;
/
```

You can also test using the 'Run' icon (or pressing control-F10) while looking at the package object editor; it's next to the compile (cogs) icon. That lets you pick a procedure/function from the package and set the argument values.
From the image of the error, you have opened the package body from the object list, it's only showing the boand you are clicking If you're now in the package body editor - not a worksheet - and clicking the compile button to get that error, then remove the SET and EXECUTE commands instead.

Comment: Thank you! It just executes the EX3 Procedure but at least its a great advance. I didnt know i had to put that on a worksheet

Comment: Do you know by any chance what could be not working out on my other procedure? It works by its own but not here :(

Comment: If you run those three commands in the worksheet as a script (F5) rather than run as a statement (control-enter) then it will execute both procedures; the script output window will show that, and the output from both.

Comment: Now i dont know why im getting a unknown command error using the f5 :(

Comment: I don't know either. Maybe you have a fragment of the script selected and it's just trying to run that fragment?

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Terminate the procedure with a slash:

```
<snip>
  END EX2;
END PAQEX;
/                                    --> this

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
EXECUTE PAQEX.EX2('AIRBUS',0);
```

Comment: Trying now but now instead the error claims: Encountered the symbol /

Comment: You shouldn't. Basically, all your PL/SQL procedures should be terminated by a slash - package body, package specification, standalone stored procedures, anonymous PL/SQL blocks, triggers, ... everything. Because, if you run the whole code as a script, Oracle will raise an error.

Comment: I created the package using the new package tool on oracle, divided in head and body. Ive read that if i use a script it is impossible to get an error with this code, but how can i solve it like this?

Comment: I can't comment on the "new package tool", I don't use it. On the other hand, I've been creating packages for 25+ years now so I guess I *know* how to properly create them. Therefore, do whatever you find appropriate.